Tools for Exact Vertex Coloring Solutions with Good Performance
I'm working on a project that requires solving the vertex coloring problem with the exact minimum k, where k represents the number of colors needed to color all vertices without monochromatic edge.
I’ve come across several tools that provide approximate solutions, but I need an exact solution. I also found algorithms that could be implemented, but I'm looking for a well-tested, efficient tool instead. While I'm aware that the problem can be reduced to an Integer Linear Programming (ILP) formulation, I’d prefer a tool specifically optimized for graph problems, as it might leverage graph theory heuristics and theorems that could enhance performance. Moving to a different domain, like ILP, might miss out on these optimizations (may be it is not true. In this case i would like to here an argumentation)
For SAT problems, tools like PySMT exist, but I'm having trouble finding something similar for exact vertex coloring. Any recommendations?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Updated:
For my study project, I'm working on implementing a reduction from the k-coloring problem to theories solvable by SMT solvers. I’d like to find tools specifically designed for solving k-coloring problems to compare their results with my reduction-based approach. I’m hoping there are tools that incorporate heuristics for improved efficiency, but I've had trouble finding them, so I decided to ask here.

Clearly, computing the chromatic number of a graph is a computationally hard problem.  There are, to my knowledge, no good alternatives here.  I suggest you look into properties of the graphs you work with, e.g. are they sparse, do they have some kind of structure you can (ab)use?  How large are they?  Is it possible to enumerate all maximal cliques thereby finding a good lower bound on the number of colors needed, etc.

SAT solvers are very good these days, and to be honest, you could do a lot worse than reducing $k$-colouring to SAT.
The standard reduction is very simple. Given an undirected graph $(V,E)$, the propositional variables are $p_{v,i}$ which means vertex $v$ has colour $i$.
There are three kinds of clause: Every vertex has a colour, a vertex has only one colour, and no two vertices connected by an edge have the same colour. In CNF:
$$\displaystyle \begin{eqnarray*}\bigvee_{1 \le i \le k} p_{v,i} & \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,& \forall v \in V \\
\neg p_{v,i} \vee \neg p_{v,j} & & \forall v \in V, 1 \le i < j \le k \\
\neg p_{v,i} \vee \neg p_{v,i} & & \forall (v,w) \in E, 1 \le i \le k\end{eqnarray*}$$
To find the minimal $k$, you will probably need to binary search.

Thank you for your response! Maybe I should update my question...
For my study project, I'm working on implementing a reduction from the k-coloring problem to theories solvable by SMT solvers. I’d like to find tools specifically designed for solving k-coloring problems to compare their results with my reduction-based approach. I’m hoping there are tools that incorporate heuristics for improved efficiency, but I've had trouble finding them, so I decided to ask here.
If you’re saying that reduction to SAT is widely used, then I suppose it could work tool. Are you familiar with another tools?

@SemyonGuretskiy Not personally, no. My background is compilers, where $k$ tends to be fixed.
